# How to implement a Parent Servlet code and so to avoid any repeated coding

Tags: servlets

I have got a lot of servlets where I have to repeat a lot of code all the time, is there any way to implement a parent servlet which will have the repeated code and the remaining ones will be using it(A inheritance kind of functionality).If yes then how to do it. Implementation is bit tougher as per my knowledge each servlet instance is a completely new object and the initialization code runs several times. Moreover each servlet instance works in a separate thread.

Comment: show us your code. what you've done so far ?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).